# How can I integrate socket.io on Karate

Tags: socket.io, karate

I know that karate has a built-in support for WebSocket, but there is anyway that can use **socket.io** on karate?

I would like to sent a message into a microservices that comunicate with socket.io, and wait the response for asserting that the message is as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't use arbitrary JavaScript libraries from Karate, and there is typically never a need to.

EDIT: if you explain what exactly you are trying to do (you can edit your question) that would make for a much more productive discussion. Karate is a testing framework. if you see a gap in the WebSockets implementation, the right thing to do is ask for a fix, see example: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/775

Or maybe all you need to do is use the Java inter-op. I know teams using this to test gRPC, JMS messaging and chat-bots that do bi-directional / async flows: https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/1128170638223364097

Comment: I would like to sent a message into a microservices that comunicate with socket.io, and wait the response for asserting that the message is as expected.